# Creating a new one sheet excel file from another excel which has too many sheets

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

When I run the below code I got this error.

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: The
>   supplied data appears to be a raw XML file. Formats such as Office
>   2003 XML are not supported

```
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId7");
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(sheet2);
```

It works fine if I write

```
   wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

insted of

```
   wb = new XSSFWorkbook(sheet2);
```

But it creates the all sheets from my old excel. I dont want it. Because my old excell is very huge.

Is there a way to create only one sheet excel file from the old excel's sheet which Relative id is "rId7" ?

Comment: Can you try to write `pkg.Move;` instead of `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);`?

Answer (score 1):

`new XSSFWorkbook()` requires an `.xlsx` file as input. That is a zip file with the .XLSX structure. It will not work if all you give it is raw XML. You can try opening the file you want, and then delete the sheets you don't want to keep.